# SpriteKit - Detect when two SKShapeNodes "pass" each other

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, collision, skphysicsbody

**It's might look long but most of it is the same code :P hope i did well explaining my self :)**
i hope i could explain my self.
This is the case : 
i have a SKShapeNode lets call  him X.
This is how i declared X(**ONLY ONCE IN didMoveToView** ):

```
 var X = SKShapeNode(circleOfRadius: 15)
        X.position = CGPointMake(100  , 100)
        X.fillColor = SKColor.yellowColor()
        X.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: coin.frame.width/2)
        X.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
        X.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 1        
        X.physicsBody?.affectedByGravity = false
        X.physicsBody?.categoryBitMask = coincategory
        X.physicsBody?.contactTestBitMask = coincategory
        self.addChild(coin)
```

Now my second SKShapeNode , lets call him Y is a little tricky,for my Game reasons, i need his size to be dynamic , so this what i did and it's working , First, Declared him in **didSimulatePhysics()** like this :

```
 override func didSimulatePhysics() {
        let pixel = self.childNodeWithName(X.name!)
        var pathtodraw : CGMutablePathRef!
        pathtodraw = CGPathCreateMutable()
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathtodraw, nil , pixel!.position.x, pixel!.position.y)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathtodraw, nil, 0, 0)
        CGPathCloseSubpath(pathtodraw)
        Y.path = pathtodraw

        self.addChild(Y)

{
```

And than for his size to be dynamic ( the game include movment of X) , i remove him everytime inside the **update**  method , so that the path could keep update itself:

```
 override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {


        Y.removeFromParent()


}
```

What i am trying to achieve : every time object X pass over Y println("They Just Passed each other"), i dont want them to react to the contact , or bounch from each other , they should be invisible to each other , but i need to detect when they pass each other.

What is the problem : When i'm adding Physics to Y , the node dosent delete him self , he keep generating more nodes and fill the screen with him self. and if left it the way it his above, it's works perefectly , it delete him self and update the size and always keep it only 1 node.
this is what tried adding to  Y :

```
override func didSimulatePhysics() {
        let pixel = self.childNodeWithName(X.name!)
        var pathtodraw : CGMutablePathRef!
        pathtodraw = CGPathCreateMutable()
        CGPathMoveToPoint(pathtodraw, nil , pixel!.position.x, pixel!.position.y)
        CGPathAddLineToPoint(pathtodraw, nil, 0, 0)
        CGPathCloseSubpath(pathtodraw)
        Y.path = pathtodraw

        self.addChild(Y)

        **linenode = SKShapeNode(path: pathtodraw)
        linenode.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFromPath: pathtodraw)**

      {
```

It Keep generates alot of nodes and dosent delete them . Any idea what can i do to accomplish that? Thanks guys !

Answer (score 0):

Since a shape node's path can be updated without removing the node from the scene and then adding it back, I suggest you add `Y` to the scene in `didMoveToView` and delete the `addToChild` and `removeFromParent` in the `didSimulatePhysics` and `update` methods. Also, add the physics body to `Y` instead of creating a new shape node. Lastly, you are creating `X` and then adding `coin` to the scene.

Comment: and where will he update the node's path dynamically?

Comment: plus + he needs to update dynamically the  Y.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeChainFromPath: Y.path)  |||||||||
            Y = SKShapeNode(path: Y.path) |||||||?

Comment: @roimulia the OP's code to update the path should work without changes. Also, I suggested that the OP add the physics body to `Y`.

Comment: What''s OP? and for some reason i checked it and they are colliding with each other for some reason . i have set the CollisionBit maks to :     let X  : UInt32 = 0x1 << 0 |||
let Y  : UInt32 = 0x1 << 1 ||| Any ideas why they dosent "pass" each other? + The Y object dosent move's and dosent change him self dynamic , do you have email that i contact you? :P i need to finish this and i can release my game .. ^^ it's all i got left :P  that would be asweome!

Comment: @roimulia OP = orignal poster (i.e., the person that asked the question). Did you try setting the physics body's `collisionBitMask` to 0?